# Proper way to apply vertical-align to child elements within a parent block element

Tags: css

What is the best way to vertically align all child elements within a containing div?

- Should I be applying `vertical-align:
  top;` to each element?
- Is it OK to
  just apply `vertical-align: top;` to
  a wildcard?

This is my test case.

CSS;

```
#wrapper * { vertical-align: top; }
#wrapper label { display: inline-block; font-weight: 700; }
```

HTML;

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <label>Label: </label><br /><span>(Sub Label)</span></div >
    <input type="textbox" />
</div>
```

And a jsFiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/vPU3z/7/

(I need to investigate this more but additionally, why, in IE7, does "label" take a block format instead of inline-block? The textbox drops under the label element.)

Comment: Your fiddle's HTML differs from what's here.

Comment: @BoltClock Apologies. I've updated the link.

Comment: The label is "block" in IE7 because it is a block element to begin with, and setting "inline-block" has no effect. You must "float" a div in < IE7 to replicate this behaviour or use another element that is not "block" to begin with such as a label. Other than that, i'm not entirely sure what the question is asking.

Comment: Basically, I want to know if it's good practice to apply vertical-align to all child elements using a wildcard?

Comment: Nope, it isn't good practice to use the wildcard selector. It is very performance intensive.

Comment: @Orange Kid: The `*` selector *can* provide suboptimal performance (not that you'd *ever* notice this). So, it's best to avoid it where possible. It's a bit [like the goto statement](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a label you should be using.. the [`<label>`  tag](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-label-tag-html-forms/):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/vPU3z/6/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <label for="example">Label: <br />(Sub Label)</label>
    <input type="text" id="example" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper label { 
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: I would assume that applying vertical-align: top to the label, the textbox would be at the bottom still. Does the browser only require one element with vertical-align: top to move everything up? (I do use labels. Just didn't put it in this example.)

Comment: @Orange Kid: Could you provide a more complete sample of your form? At the moment, I don't think the your provided code is complete enough to give you a proper answer of how you should style it. Why would you make an example using a different tag to your actual code?

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant to the question. I just wanted to know how to vertically-align all elements within a block-level element. I've updated the example with something more like what ASP.NET would spit out.

Comment: @Orange Kid: I still don't really get it. Also, you still have `type="textbox`, which is not a valid value. Is this what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/vPU3z/8/ ? You apply `vertical-align: top` to as many elements that need it, which in this case seems to be only `#wrapper label`.

Comment: That's what I want. What I don't understand is why applying `vertical-align: top` to the label brings the text box to the top as well. Does applying that to one element force the other elements to align too?

Comment: @Orange Kid: It's just how `display: inline-block` works. See: http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html You can set any of the different `vertical-align` values in my last demo, and it will behave like the elements on that page.

Answer (score 0):

For your label:

```
#label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that goofs things up further. http://jsfiddle.net/GPtn7/3/ Also, this would need to be applied to each label in my form.